# Ajax script not working properly how to know call to servlet is made by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I have started AJAX with servlets but my first program is not working. Here is the code:

```
<form action="./ajax" method="get" id="myAjaxRequestForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="address" id="address"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Register" />
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(event){
        alert();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var name = $('#email').val();
        var name = $('#address').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:   "GET",
            url:    'ajax',
            data:   "name = " +name+ "&email="+email+"&address"+address,
            success: function(msg){ 
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("Error");
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

```java
public class ajax extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {       
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String address = req.getParameter("address");
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(email);
        System.out.println(address);
        PrintWriter p = res.getWriter();
        p.println("success");
    }
}
```

This program has to display a popup with the success or failure message but it redirects to a page with servlet message. It is not showing the popup.
When using an XML file I have no issues.

Comment: You have a syntax error: the `event.preventDefault();` should be within the click handler function, not in the `$.ajax` options object. Always check the console when your JavaScript code doesn't work as you expect, normally you'll find an error to help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: thanks Sir its working now.

Comment: Glad to help. I added a full answer for you as I saw several other issues in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems. Firstly you're assigning the value of all your inputs to the `name` variable instead of their own variables. The manual creation of those variables is redundant anyway as you can simply use the `serialize()` method on the `form` anyway.

Secondly, the `preventDefault()` call should be within the anonymous function you provide to the `click` handler, not within the `$.ajax` settings object.

Finally you should hook to the submit event of the form, not the click event of the submit button. Try this:

```
$('#myAjaxRequestForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'ajax',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(msg){ 
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

Final tip; always use `console.log` to debug. `alert()` coerces all types to string, so you may not be seeing the correct data.